# Error when connecting to MS LDAP using Apache LDAP AIP

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap

I'm using Apache LDAP API to connect to MS Active Directory but I'm getting the following error:

> **DEBUG#c.s.m.c.r.c.ApacheLdapClient##anonymous#http-bio-8080-exec-6###Unexpected error connecting to LDAP org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapAuthenticationExcepti
> on: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580^@**

In this case I´m just provided the LDAP user name and password both in the LdapConnectionConfig.Name and in the bind method of LdapConnect class.

Based on some researches and tests I could see that when I provide the complete DN (Distinguished Name) of the user the connection and bind works fine.

So my question is: Is there a way to get connected and bind to MS AD using the Apache LDAP API just providing the user name and password (not the complete DN)?

*Below are excerpt of of the source code that fails:*

```html
LdapConnection conn = new LdapNetworkConnection();
connParams.setLdapHost(LDAP_HOST);
connParams.setLdapPort(389);
connParams.setName(test_user);
connParams.setCredentials(TEST_USER_PASSWORD);

LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(connParams);

connection.bind(test_user, TEST_USER_PASSWORD);
```

**And this one is that works fine:**

```html
LdapConnection conn = new LdapNetworkConnection();
connParams.setLdapHost(LDAP_HOST);
connParams.setLdapPort(389);
connParams.setName(CN=test_user,DC=Example,DC=com);
connParams.setCredentials(TEST_USER_PASSWORD);

LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(connParams);

connection.bind(CN=test_user,DC=Example,DC=com, TEST_USER_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the distinguished name for binding - LDAP doesn't know about Active Directory, after all.  Of course, you can use a service account first to retrieve the dn for a sAMAccountName.

Answer (score -1):

This should work with test_user@example.com, the shortest format accepted by MS AD for binding.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).